# CSS, jQuery Slope/slant menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu

Im trying to figure out how can i achieve such effect:
http://i43.tinypic.com/11j9h00.jpg

Slope menu which expands to the left.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

if this should be like a regular dropdown with the only difference that the menuitems are not in on line, then yes this is possible. You could use a normal menu and use jquery to shift the position or padding.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution:

```
$('ul.menu li').each(function() {
    var marginLeft = 0; // start margin left position in pixels
    var stapLeft = 50; // pixels

    // looping through every li item underneave a ul in the list
    $(this).find('ul li').each(function() {
        // set the margin for the element
        $(this).css(marginLeft, marginLeft);
        // set for the next item the margin
        marginLeft += stapLeft;
    });
});
```

But there is defently a better way to do it :) its just to point you in a direction